# POSIxt and POSIXct Date Comaprison Count in R

Tags: r, rodbc

I created a data table called ltfs from a table I loaded in through a ODBC connection that was named ltfs

```
ltfs<-data.table(ltfs)
```

In this table there is a column with a date field in it. When I check the class of that column it returns "POSIXct" "POSIXt". When I check what the dates look like they are in the form of ex. 2014-01-01. I am trying to count the number of entries with a date in this field less than a certain date. I tried using the .N feature but am getting an error that has to do with the way the date formats are. My code is below any help would be much appreciated.

```
ltfs<-data.table(ltfs)
datecount<-ltfs[Eligibility_Date<=as.Date("2011-01-01"),.N]
```

I know it has to do with the date format (either the criteria or the format of the dates in the table) just not sure how to handle them.

Comment: If I remember correctly, RODBC messes up the dates structure and converts them to characters while keeping the `Date` class. Can you provide `dput(head(ltfs$Eligibility_Date))`? Eitherway, I'd recommend to try to convert them to dates again using `ltfs[, Eligibility_Date := as.IDate(Eligibility_Date)]` and then try again.

Comment: structure(c(1274158800, 1376629200, 1327644000, 1367211600, 1357192800, 
1382936400), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "")

Comment: Try doing something like `ltfs[, sum(Eligibility_Date<="2011-01-01")]`

Comment: That works perfect after I converted to dates using the as.IDate.

Comment: NP, glad you solved it. I remember having a similar mess with RODBC which took me quite a while to solve.